# Custom Async Validator in Reactive Forms Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement a Async Validator in my Reactive forms But i am getting errors please help.

**Validator**

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export function  validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<{[key : number] : any}>{
    console.log(c);
    // return this.validateAgeObservable(c.value);
    return this.validateAgeObservable(c.value).first();
  }

  function validateAgeObservable( age: number ) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(age === 20 ? null : {asyncInvalid: true});
      // observer.complete(); or this or .first();
    });
  }
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit(){
this.user = new FormGroup({
      ....
      age:new FormControl('',null,validate),
      ....
}
```

I get this following Error Please help

[image]

If i remove the async validator it works fine.

**UPDATE**

After richards solution it works but i want it to work for number field why its not working when its a number ?

and one more thing i noticed on page load the validator is called thrice why is that so ?

Comment: The `ValidationErrors` has a key of type *string*, not *number*. I don't know if changing that will make any difference, or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
export function validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> {
  console.log(c);
  return validateAgeObservable(c.value).first();
}

function validateAgeObservable(age: number): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(age === 20 ? null : { 'asyncInvalid': true });
  });
}
```

I changed the `key` type to `string`, and I removed the `this` from the front the of the `validateAgeObservable` call inside the `validate` function.

It compiles, and doesn't show any errors in the console, so I am assuming this will work when pressed.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Richards but i need it for a number field like age how to make it work with number it should right with number also. this same is working in template driven

Comment: I guess I was wrong in my assumption. :) Do you get an error when you try to use this on a number field?